# Как использовать загрузочную USB?

Tags: linux, windows, ос, bios, kali-linux

Записал Linux дистрибутив на флешку с помощью rufus. Я хочу использовать эту систему на флешке, но основную систему Windows сносить не хочу. Так вот, как запустить записанный образ диска через BIOS и обратно переключиться на основную ОС,и нужно создавать разделы? Смотрел много видео на эту тему на ютубе, много воды и непонятного.

Comment: Воткнуть флешку, перезагрузиться, в меню биоса выбрать желаемое загрузочное устройство

Comment: а как обратно  ?

Comment: Перезагрузиться и не лезть в меню загрузки (флешку можно вынуть, когда появится экран БИОС).

Comment: Перезагрузиться, в меню биоса выбрать другое желаемое загрузочное устройство (или ничего не выбирать, чтобы выбралось устройство само в соответствии с прописанными в биосе настройками)

Comment: спасибо за ваши ответы